# Custom KeyCode Variable

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, keypress

I'm creating a virtual launchpad, and I am going to have this one script attached to each button, but I need it to be modular so that I don't need 64 different scripts that do the exact same thing.

My issue is I'm not sure how I can get KeyCodes a public variables. So if I declared a public variable named "theKey":

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.theKey))
{ //play sound etc. 
}
```

Something similar to that so that in unity I can use the inspector to insert what the hotkey will be for the button this script is attached to.

KeyCode.String doesn't work, and I need full KeyCodes like .Alpha2

```
public class LaunchManager : MonoBehaviour {

// Define public variables
public Button b11;

// Initialization
void Start () {
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    var pointer = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);

    // For Single Use (sound emmission) 
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2)) {
        // Click Button from keypress
        ExecuteEvents.Execute(b11.gameObject, pointer, ExecuteEvents.pointerDownHandler);
        // Play Sound
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    }

    // Execute while clicking
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha2)) {
        //set button colour to pressed state
    }

  }
}
```

Any help much appreciated. I did check around thoroughly for an answer to this. If I'm still missing relevant details let me know and I will respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to make a public Keycode variable which is done as such:

```
public Keycode theKey = Keycode.None;
```

and you can use it like:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(theKey))
{

//Do code

}
```